# How to create custom registration and login form in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new very to learning Drupal8.

Could you please help me out to create custom Registration and Login form for in Drupal8? I have found some solution but that didn't help for me.

And can we create Register and login form using template in Drupal8?

Thank you..!!

Comment: Drupal has login and registration forms built in core, why do you need custom ones?
You can expand/alter the existing ones and apply your own template file.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your response. :)  I will try to do the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
        
            //render the login forms
              $form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class) ;
              $render = Drupal::service('renderer');
              $variables['login_form'] = $render->renderPlain($form);
            
        
            //render the register form
              $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->create(array());
              $formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                 ->getFormObject('user', 'register')
                 ->setEntity($entity);
              $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);
              $variables['register_form'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form);   
}
```

Use the below variables in twig page. For login -

```
{{ login_form }}
```

For register -

```
{{ register_form }}
```

Comment: Okay...Thank you..!!